# Custom UITableViewCell without dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a custom UITableViewCell:

**TestTableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestTableViewCell : UITableViewCell 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testCellLabel;

@end
```

**TestTabelViewCell.m**

```
#import "TestTableViewCell.h"

@implementation TestTableViewCell

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        _testCellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

And then I have view controller with a table view that uses the custom table view cell. However this issue is that I don't want to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier within the cellForRowAtIndexPath. I instead want to have an array of cells.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TestTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *myTableViewCells;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSArray *)myTableViewCells {
    TestTableViewCell *cell1 = [[TestTableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell1.testCellLabel.text = @"one";
    cell1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    TestTableViewCell *cell2 = [[TestTableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell2.testCellLabel.text = @"two";
    cell1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    if (!_myTableViewCells) {
        _myTableViewCells = @[cell1, cell2];
    }

    return _myTableViewCells;
}

#pragma mark - UITableView delegate functions

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.myTableViewCells.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TestTableViewCell *cell = self.myTableViewCells[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

The problem is that there is no `testCellLabel` appearing in the table view cell. I know the cells are there, because I set their background colour.

After talking to a few people, apparently I need to do some sort of loading from the XIB or the NIB for the UI to load properly? Even though the label is defined in the cell in the storyboard.

I know this is going against the norm and that Apple really wants you to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, but I know it won't work in the situation I need it in. I have done the reading on that much so ***please*** don't just tell me to use it. This code example is just very basic for example sake and ease of use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where do you call this myTableViewCells method?

Comment: I **will** tell you to just use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. I doubt you have a scenario where it would not work. You **will** have issues with UITableView complaining that you did not get the cell from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: Why can't use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`? I can't believe it ==!

Comment: @Mr.T The myTableViewCells method is a custom setter

Answer (score 3):

```
 TestTableViewCell *cell1 = [[TestTableViewCell alloc] init];
```

Creates a new `TestTableViewCell` object and does not instantiate it from the storyboard like you're thinking it does. Therefor all outlets created will be nil and simply not show up. The fact that you can set the background colour is not evidence that your implementation works.

You *need* to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. You say that it doesn't work for your problem.. show me how it doesn't work and I will tell you why you're wrong.

**Edit**

I see in your comments you say your cell needs a custom setter. Well, when you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you can do all setup work in `awakeFromNib` (If using a xib file) OR `initWithCoder` if you are using the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can create cell without `dequeueResableCellWithIdentifer`.

```
[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:<#UITableCellStyle#> resueIdentifier:<#(nullable *NSString)#>]
```